# Integrate Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I have some JavaScript which talks through an outgoing web hook in Slack in order to read a Slack post, do some computation on it, and then post back as a bot.  I have this working fine, but I would like to store information in a database from these messages. (Basically, I would like to keep track of points and provide a point update to Slack).

I have a Python script set up to talk to the database and that works fine in updating the database with the new point values etc.. My problem is trying to get the JavaScript talk to Python and Python talk to JavaScript... I need to pass two strings (name of person to get more points, and how many points to add) from JavaScript to Python and then pass one integer/string from Python to JavaScript.

I've been scouring the web for hours and I have come up with the fact from forums that it likely has something to do with cgi/JSON/AJAX/JQuery but I am getting lost in the execution.  Can anyone explain how to make these two talk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't have any experience using Slack, but I think that doesn't really matter. There are several pieces you need to put together for this to work. First, you have your Python script, which you say it works ok - I'm guessing the script works by manually running it from the terminal, so you need a way of *exposing* it to the internet.

**That's what you called *cgi*.**

There are many ways of doing this, but it basically boils down to having a web server with an **endpoint** that, when accessed, launches your script with the appropriate parameters and returns its output. As you seem familiar with Python, I'd advise you to take a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), a really easy to use microframework that will allow you to set up a small web application.  There are several ways of running your web application, particularly depending on what web server you're using. A quick Google search will show many tutorials about that matter.

Also, it's important that you properly format the messages sent from the backend to your web frontend and viceversa. **That's why you've mentioned JSON**. It's a great way of passing messages back and forth. You can easily convert Python objects (like `dicts`) to JSON using built-in and third party libraries.

In order to dynamically request and load information from the frontend without refreshing your website, you'll need some kind of *asynchronous* procedure. **That's what AJAX is about**. It's a mechanism of sending and receiving information asynchronously, so your website can keep going while the information is still to be received.

However, doing AJAX requests by hand in a cross-browser compatible way is a PITA, so **you're better off using jQuery** and it's AJAX-related functions.

So those would be the elements and step you should follow to make JavaScript talk to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that myself but you should be able to write javascript data into a json file which can be read by Python via json module.

[how to write json files in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027101/how-to-write-json-files-in-javascript)

http://pymotw.com/2/json/